# JMS with apache camel in ServiceMix generates an error

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I've got a problem with JMS access in spring, I try to configure JMS consumer and get an error:

> Class
>   org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor
>   does not implement the requested
>   interface
>   java.util.concurrent.Executor

Does any one know how to solve this, or what this really means? I'm using Camel 2.4 and am deploying my service to ServiceMix 3.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Spring 2.x.

It seems that [Spring 2.x SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) does not implement the Java core [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface. To resolve this, you have 2 options I can think of right off the bat:

1. Upgrade to Spring 3.x. [That version of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) does implement the [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface.
2. Use a different [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) implementation. Java core has the built in [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), or you can use the [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to construct a variety of different configurations of the same.

Hope that helps.

//Nicholas

Comment: That is the reason, but solution in my case should be to switch to Apache Camel 2.5 :) - or as you've written, switch Servicemix to Spring 3.x, which seems quite hard.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe recompile camel-jms using spring 2.5 which oddly may help. Check camel building source docu as there is a maven profile to use spring 2.5.